# Error adding menuentry Windows 10 after reinstall Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows, windows-10

I've installed Windows 10 boot on `/dev/sda1` but grub2 doesn't detect that as operating system.

```
$ fdisk -l

Device      Boot    Start       End         Blocks      Id  System
/dev/sda1   *       2048        2050047     1024000     b   W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2           2050048     232736767   115343360   7   HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4           232738814   500117503   133689345   f   W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5           476450816   492834815   8192000     82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6           492836864   500117503   3640320     83  Linux
/dev/sda7           232738816   476450815   121856000   83  Linux
```

For that reason I added a menuentry in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` leaving the file as

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries. Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment. Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry 'Windows 10' {
set root ='(hd0,msdos1)'
chainloader +1
}
```

But when I try to get into the Windows 10, I receive this error

**ERROR**

```
error: not an assigment.
error: invalid signature.

Press any key to continue...
```

But I tried to boot with SuperGrub usb disk and it detected the OS and I could boot without problems.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not a big problem this time, but can you use `LANG=C` when your command's output is localized? For example `LANG=C fdisk -l`, this way the output will be in english

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work

Comment: btw, I don't think it is `/etc/grub.d/40_default` but it is `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`

Comment: yes, my mistake, /etc/grub.d/40_custom

Comment: it was just a misspelling in the question. I was actually using /etc/grub.d/40_custom. It is still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the menuentry to below:

```
menuentry 'Windows 10' {
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)' #No 'space' between 'root' and '='
    chainloader +1
    }
```

works for me. I tried this and it took me back to Windows bootloader (installed in my `sda1`). So I guess it should work for you as well.

Comment: Yes, it works, a simple space was the cause of all the problems! I could become crazy to find this.